# glassfish and tomcat print date as question marks after creating respective services in windows 10

Tags: java, windows, date, tomcat, glassfish

glassfish and tomcat prints date correctly if service is not created, 
but after creating it as a service, date is printed wrongly.

Even in glassfish log the datetime is coming as **????-??-??T??:??:??.???+0530**

Sample Code from java that prints wrongly when `Locale.XX` is not provided as parameter in `SimpleDateFormat` .

```
String dateInString = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(new Date());
out.println(dateInString);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
??-??-???? ??:??:??
```

When `Local.XX` was provided:

```
String pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mms";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.UK);
out.println(formatter.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());
out.println(new Date());
out.println(formatter.format(new Date()));
out.println(formatter.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());
```

**OUTPUT**

```
India Standard Time
Thu Apr 12 10:40:04 IST 2018
04-12-2018 10:40:04
India Standard Time
```

GlassFish Version:  4.1.2
Java Version: 1.8.0_161

Initially the Datetime format for the system was set in Marati Language, and was later changed to English, but that did not solve the issue.
The problem exists only in this specific system. Other systems with same configurations have no issues.

Comment: same thing happened to me, Glassfish error seems https://ibb.co/dUjdBc